# Failed Android Studio library

Tags: android

Welcome
I am facing a problem when adding any Android Studio library, as this error always appears:

Failed to resolve: com.github.billthefarmer:mididriver:v1.24
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Which library do I want to add this error appears, in the above example I tried a library com.github.billthefarmer:mididriver:v1.24
But most libraries are not loaded

I tried Android Studio update !

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing this issue because:

- You haven't added the JitPack repository. Please include the following code in your project's `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

For more info check documenation https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver

- There could be a problem with your internet connection or a firewall may be blocking the download of the library.

Comment: I turned off the security software and my internet is very fast, but to no avail!
Note that he is adding some libraries and some of them show this error. I do not know where the problem is exactly